# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-confirm-dialog'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Vue.js + node.js is the basis of my app. I wanted to use the `vue-confirm-dialog` package from npm but this code line leads to an error:

```
import VueConfirmDialog from 'vue-confirm-dialog'
```

I have already executed: `npm install --save vue-confirm-dialog` and the module vue-confirm-dialog appears in the package.json file.

The error message `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-confirm-dialog'` still appears.

Comment: Have you checked it's present in your node_modules ?

Comment: Yes there is a vue-confirm-dialog folder in node_modules

Comment: Had a similar issue once, try restarting the server.

Comment: I already restarted the dev-server, the IDE and the PC. Error still occurs.

Comment: @MichaB Can you please cross check the version you have and the version on which this supports.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal package.json: ^1.1.0 and package-lock.json: 1.1.0. It is the latest version.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Had the same issue today, solved it by downgrading vue-confirm-dialog to 1.0.2.

```
npm install vue-confirm-dialog@1.0.2 --save
```